# Active Admin rails, how to escape html before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

i'm new of rails and since few days i'm playing with active admin.
I'm using it to manage data of an old legacy system.

I have a issue: i need to save an html string into table, but escaped and i dont find a solution for this.

Example, i want to save this

```
<b>Ciao</b> mondo!
```

Like that

```
&lt;p&gt;Ciao &lt;b&gt;Mondo!&lt;/p&gt;
```

With this block of code i can show it correctly in index page, but when i try to add new or edit it doesn't excape correctly

```
  index do
     column :label
     column (:value_it) { |e| raw(e.value_it) }
     column (:value_en) { |e| raw(e.value_en) }
     column (:value_es) { |e| raw(e.value_es) }
     default_actions
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> CGI.escapeHTML '<b>Ciao</b> mondo!'
=> "&lt;b&gt;Ciao&lt;/b&gt; mondo!"
irb(main):002:0> CGI.unescapeHTML( CGI.escapeHTML '<b>Ciao</b> mondo!' )
=> "<b>Ciao</b> mondo!"
```

plug it into `before_save` hook on the model and you're good to go